# In typescript, how do you define a self referencing recursive data structure?

Tags: typescript

I have a self referencing recursive data structure that can look like any of the following:

```js
const a = {
  s: "a",
  n: 0,
}

const a = {
  s: "a",
  n: 0,
  userDefinedName: {
    s: "b",
    n: 1,
  }
}

const a = {
  s: "a",
  n: 0,
  userDefinedName: {
    s: "b",
    n: 1,
    someName: {
      s: "c"
      n: 2,
    }
  }
}

const a = {
  s: "a",
  n: 0,
  userDefinedName: {
    s: "b",
    n: 1,
  },
  userDefinedName2: {
    s: "c",
    n: 2,
  }
}
```

I can't seem to figure out how to type it. Below are a few attempts with the typescript errors I receive in comments.

```
type A = {
  // Property 's' of type 'string' is not assignable to 'string' index type 'A'.
  s: string;
  // Property 'n' of type 'number' is not assignable to 'string' index type 'A'.
  n: number;
  [key: string]: A;
};


type A = {
  s: string;
  n: number;
};

type B = {
  [K in keyof A]: A[K];
  // Error: A mapped type may not declare properties or methods.
  [key: string]: B;
};
```

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but cannot seem to figure it out, hopefully someone can point me in the right direction and help explain what I'm missing? Thanks.

Comment: You can apply some restrictions/prefix to `use${string}` property. See [example](https://tsplay.dev/mMxDkN)

Comment: I hadn't seen that syntax before, and it's good to know! It doesn't cover the any string can be a key case though. Really I need the "any string except s and n", which appears to not be in typescript.

Comment: Do you want to allow only one extra property? or there might be several `any strings` on the same level?

Comment: there could be several `any strings` on a given level, and obviously can nest.

Comment: In this case, you need an extra function to infer an object and validate the properties. [example](https://tsplay.dev/WP7Dem)

Comment: I appreciate the additional insight into typescript! Between all of the responses, it's looking like what I want is not directly supported in typescript. There are a handful of workarounds but nothing that would allow me define an object as `const b: B = {s:"s",n:0};` without type errors (or incorrect type definitions)

Comment: Btw, you can find more examples of using recursive data structures in my blog [here](https://catchts.com/recursive-ds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define it using two types: a base type and the recursive type: an intersection of the base and a type having optional string properties which reference itself:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZ2gXigbwFBSggXD4AJwEsA7AcwG4spT9SBXAWwCMJDqBfajUSKAKIAPOEzAAbFLETQAZFAAKcQsGJxxAHjRQA2gGsIIfAiJlyAXXzDRE6JwB8PACYQAxuOXRXAe1ImoECJiklZBttSBNpIAdAiUUAD0CQQkFBiRwRDRpPFJtMxshOlhMQjeTBDAABZmAuJIucnWmVAAPlAMpC4AZmQQTsVRWXCk3tXsCoTeYI2CJdDtnT19A4OZ0WBTYAD8sbMmqeRtHV0QvaT9a7YbW7s5icmMrOzHS2crVzGb07vfMw9zIavU7nS4YPKVVzRaFAA)

```ts
type Base = {
  s: string;
  n: number;
};

type Example = Base & Partial<{ [key: string]: Example }>;

declare const example: Example;
example.s; // string
example.n; // number
example.somethingElse; // Example | undefined
example.anotherProp; // Example | undefined

example.prop?.s; // string | undefined
example.prop?.n; // number | undefined
example.prop?.prop; // Example | undefined

// etc...
```

Comment: Can't seem to assign the example structures without a type error?

Comment: @JeremyK That's how you can create the type. As far as applying it: TS doesn't have a mechanism to express "all strings except literal strings `"a"` and `"b"`", so the [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) can only create an intersection from the types of the keys in `Base` and the `Example` type itself, which prevents assigning to such a property without an assertion. So, AFAIK, you'll have to use an assertion to apply this type to a value. (I'd love to be informed otherwise and proven wrong,  but I think this is currently a type system limitation.)

Comment: Forgive me, but what do you mean by you'll have to use an assertion to apply the type? The solution above appeared to work at first glance, but you obviously poked some holes in it. I'm hoping this isn't a limitation as it seems like it should be achievable.

Comment: @JeremyK a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions)

Comment: Got it. So your example does work then if you change the object definition from `const a: Example = { s: "s", n: 0 };` to `const a = {s: "s", n: 0} as Example;`. That seems lack luster having to force consumers to use a type assertion (cast) each time they need to use the type? I understand that you're saying it might be a language limitation though.

Answer (score 1):

You were close in your second attempt, you can accomplish this via creating a union type `AB` and intersecting B with A:

```ts
type A = {
  s: string;
  n: number;
}

type AB = A | string | number

type B = A & {
  [key: index]: AB
}
```

By putting in a filler type `AB`, you can handle the occurrence of deeply nested objects in the shape of `A`

You can see this working in this typescript [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAgjAvDA3sGGYGcBc2QBOAlgHYDm6mJeJArgLYBGUBwAvsKJLHAEJLwYAH3zFywmHSYtO4aDH7IEAMlSUMAbQDWUMHiyFSZALp4+7TgGMA9iQMwAhnkVqMuGACIHHgDSVqMAAMfhzANnYgMIzOAmhueF6+-njBlLRYLAAiUABmpFAAJgByDvRQeHGY7h6MSZiSeACMfhgcoeH2ljHIldXeLQ1BA+lZufnFpeWuVQm1AxgBzerY1mUlZRXL8Z6WdfWDAEzLHK0WYbb2Bd3TfXsBqRgjBNl5JIXrU5XbNXsLTQNsYYZZ5jN4TMoHTb1aq7eaHAHsIA)

Comment: That doesn't contain a typescript error on the definition but it gives an error if I try and use it. I.e. `const a: B = { s: "a", n: 0 }; ` fails to meet the definition.

Comment: I have updated my answer and it is passing [all of the use cases you originally mentioned](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAgjAvDA3sGGYGcBc2QBOAlgHYDm6mJeJArgLYBGUBwAvsKJLHAEJLwYAH3zFywmHSYtO4aDH7IEAMlSUMAbQDWUMHiyFSZALp4+7TgGMA9iQMwAhnkVqMuGACIHHgDSVqMAAMfhzANnYgMIzOAmhueF6+-njBlLRYLAAiUABmpFAAJgByDvRQeHGY7h6MSZiSeACMfhgcoeH2ljHIldXeLQ1BA+lZufnFpeWuVQm1AxgBzerY1mUlZRXL8Z6WdfWDAEzLHK0WYbb2Bd3TfXsBqRgjBNl5JIXrU5XbNXsLTQNsYYZZ5jN4TMoHTb1aq7eaHAHsIA)

Comment: Thanks! The union portion is definitely a bit awkward, but i'll chalk it up to something to learn and get used to.

Comment: I got it from looking over how the creator of typescript [did it](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3496#issuecomment-128553540). Fun question to work on

Comment: @about14sheep There are currently issues with accessing nested properties using the types in this answer: https://tsplay.dev/wgXO6N

Comment: @jsejcksn yep. that and I dont think the `anotherProp` can be a string either. I think any other property besides s and n needs to be of type `A`. Correct me if im wrong @JeremyK Ill keep at it

Comment: I was also continuing to play with it, and was starting to observe the issues that @jsejcksn was pointing out. And yes, any property other than s and n should be of type B (has s and n with the optional nesting)

Comment: [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoKUDOAuTwBOAlgHYDmA3GlETkQK4C2ARhHhQL4UqiRQBCCsKAB9kldAG0A1hBA4M+YiQC6OXig4oUAYwD2ReVACGqganTYoAcksAaStSgAGdZt37gURicRnMOS4y29jiOduhgeDpgOL7m-o5B6OgOoWJQEVEwMWlxVolJySFpbJRsYUZEOsAAFiwACpHRVoa4hKS2UAD0nVA6klAA-OqcjAB0GGRdPfJtJChjRJPdrYrzoxlgA+NLAFQ5BegAeigNUSygVhiWUAAmOhAYVFVQEAAeBAZ6UNzQljC8llGlFOkDwF0sV1u90elQ8bw+Hi+P0uCnaowAFAAmADM2IAnABKKA7TqaMYbLaLLp7A6044g84gKxEa53B5POHvT5Eb7gX7-QHAxqM5ms6Ecl5cxE85EQ1EkQFY3GE4mkoA) handles the edge case of another string besides ‘s’ property.